# ¿Por qué deberían ser mis variable finales siempre? Java

Tags: java

más que un problema técnico, es una duda con el que me enfrenté alguna vez y hoy en día con más conocimientos me gustaría preguntar.

Pues en uno de los proyectos que tuve la oportunidad de colaborar me pedían que todas, o bueno casi todas las variables deberían ser final, o declaradas como finales. Me explico mediante un ejemplo.

```
public class OtherClass{

private String attributt1;
private MyClass myClass;
public void insert(final String miVariable){

     final Any any = new Any();
     any.setAny("...");
     //// MORE
     final int number = 10;
     final Any otherAny = method_that_returns_something();
     /***  MORE ***/
}

public void setAttributt1(final String attr){
     this.attributt1 = attr;
     /*** MORE CODE ***/
}

public void addXYZ(final MyClass myClassVar){
     this.myClass= myClassVar;
     /*** MORE  CODE ***/
}
}
```

Como vemos, hay varias lugares en lo que se pudo omitir la declaración como final. Pero en aquella ocasión era SONAR el que lo sugería.

Entiendo que sonar, funciona según la configuración que se realice. Pero me entra la duda porque se haría así, en solicitar las variables como finales aun cuando no las necesite. En su momento la única razón que encontré, es que era de más fácil lectura, es decir, al encontrarme con una variable final, me aseguraba que el valor o su referencia, no iba a cambiar en el bloque de código.

Esto genera gran tranquilidad, ya que asegura que en ningún otra parte la variable iba a cambiar de referencia. Por temas de mantenimiento, y esas cosas.

Sin embargo, hoy me preguntaron, que costo tiene a nivel de recursos. Es decir: ¿ayuda a ahorrar recursos de la máquina virtual de Java? ¿los mantiene iguales? ¿el garbage collector notará la diferencia entre si es final y por tanto realizará la liberación de recursos con mayor prioridad?.

Dejo, este comentario para leer opiniones, o sencillamente es una buena o mala práctica.

Atentamente,

Comment: No _deben_ llevarlo siempre. En algunos casos será absolutamente necesario, pero diría que no en la mayoría. Creo que la pregunta aquí es para quién te puso esa regla en ese proyecto particular. Saludos.

Comment: La palabra `final` indica que una variable no puede volver a asignarsele un nuevo valor después de una asignación, normalmente se debe utilizar en variables que por algún motivo no deberian cambiar su valor ej: `private final String encripKey = 'XDFRTGB64D'`, a nadie le conviene que una llave crptográfica cambie. (este es un ejemplo, no una sugerencia de almacenar llaves criptográficas en código), este tema es muy habitual en conversaciones de inmutabilidad

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias preguntas similares, de diferente antigüedad, en SO, así que podemos asumir que es un tema recurrente:

- [Perfomance (2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266806/is-there-any-performance-reason-to-declare-method-parameters-final-in-java)
- [Perfomance in Java 8 (2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054717/are-the-effectively-final-variables-interpreted-as-final-by-comiler-in-java-8)
- [Perfomance (2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521587/java-final-performance-optimization)

La conclusión en todas ellas es constante: no hay ganancia significativa en términos de rendimiento. Es un tema de limpieza de código y de estilos.
Algunos consideran importante remarcar que los parámetros o las variables locales son constantes y otros desarrolladores lo ven como ruido que alarga las sentencias innecesariamente.

Comment: Buenas, si las tienes declaradas, "atributos" el "garbage collector" no las va a borrar porque pertenecen a la clase. Por tanto siempre van a estar consumiendo recursos. Hay que evitar declarar por declarar, sabiendo cuando esas variables pertenecen (están ligadas a la clase), por ejemplo en una clase persona, atributos serían el nombre, el dni.. pero por ejemplo otras variables, a nivel de bloque para que el gc las borre porque no se necesitan. Si te pidieron final, será porque estaban en ese proyecto con esa estructura, pero tú haces un .set, por tanto, no tendría mucho sentido hacerla final

Comment: aunque útiles los links, considero que deberían quedar mas en la zona de comentarios (a la cual si tienes acceso) que como una "respuesta"

Comment: @shadow Tienes toda la razón. Estaba escribiendo una respuesta cuando me surgió una emergencia y parece que en lugar de a cancelar le di a enviar y se publicó incompleta